# git upgrade 2.10.3 breaking git-man on ubuntu 14 Trusty

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04

I have created an deb package for git 2.10.3 and installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

during monthly patching I am getting bellow error.

```
root@host3:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git-man : Breaks: git (< 1:1.7.4~rc1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Below is the installed packages of git on the server:

```
root@host03:~# dpkg --list  | grep git
iF  git                                  2.10.3-1                                   amd64        Akamai git
iU  git-man                              1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.7                         all          fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)
ii  libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64              1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - ASN.1 library
ii  libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64             1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - GSSAPI support library
ii  libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64            1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - crypto library
ii  libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64           1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - Base library
ii  libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64           1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - NTLM support library
ii  libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64             1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - X509 support library
ii  libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64             1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - libraries
ii  libroken18-heimdal:amd64             1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - roken support library
ii  librtmp0:amd64                       2.4+20121230.gitdf6c518-1ubuntu0.1         amd64        toolkit for RTMP streams (shared library)
ii  libwind0-heimdal:amd64               1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2            amd64        Heimdal Kerberos - stringprep implementation
ii  libxml-security-c17:amd64            1.7.2-2                                    amd64        C++ library for XML Digital Signatures (runtime)
ii  locales                              2.13+git20120306-12.1                      all          common files for locale support
ii  screen                               4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9                 amd64        terminal multiplexer with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation
root@stag-devprod-stash03:~#
```

Since I have upgrade git to git 2.10.3 which has documents also,
why git-man depends on git and how to fix the error "git-man : Breaks: git (< 1:1.7.4~rc1)"

Comment: Probably you should install your version of git-man as well. But such question would rather belong to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Its resolved. used command "apt-mark hold git" and updated man pages manually.